# Retraining favored class points

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-advancement

Taking the [retraining rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCampaign/campaignSystems/retraining.html) from Ultimate Campaign's Campaing systems, how would a character retrain a favored class point to be used for a different purpose? Would it fall under retraining skills? HPs? Class features?

Example: Theia is a level 7 human witch who devoted all of her FC points towards skill ranks. What if I wanted to switch those 7 FC points to the human FC bonus, of her familiar learning extra spells? How would that work? (Her INT bonus is +7 fwiw.)

Answer (score 1):

Just read carefully. Retraining a favored class point is not on the list. For retraining a class level it is directly written that

> This retraining does not allow you to reselect the feats your character gains at odd levels or the ability score increases your character gains every four levels (though you can retrain those options separately)

One could presume that if you retrain a level, you, as it is written, do not automatically retrain and reselect your feats and ability score increases, but everything else related to a level up is automatically retrained. So, rules-as-written, that's your only possible way of reallocating a favored class point.

In your case of 7 points being reallocated it would cost 6*7=35 days, as your class for sure does have the synergy with itself.